# How to replace @ in email address with <z>@</z> and not get &lt; used instead

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using Razor with MVC3 and ASP.NET4.5

I need to display jim@bloggs.com in a HTML email.

Due to issues with email clients adding mailto links to email addresses I need to alter them to prevent this happening. One recommendation is to add a non existent tag such as <z>. I have tried:

```
@(username.Replace("@","<z>@</z>"))
```

But this outputs:

```
jim&lt;z&gt;@&lt;/z&gt;bloggs.com
```

How can I ensure I get the following in the HTML:

```
jim<z>@</z>bloggs.com
```

I suspect some tweak to :

```
@(username.Replace("@","<z>@</z>"))
```

is the answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@Html.Raw()` method, because string escaping is turned on by default in Razor.

```
@Html.Raw(username.Replace("@","<z>@</z>"))
```

Though there will be security considerations for this matter as it's a potentially XSS vulnerability, so  you would better escape the initial value of the username at first and after that apply your tag insertion.